# Filtering out by multiple criteria in R

Tags: r, filter, out

I'm trying to create a separate df in R by filtering out observations based on specific criteria, but when using filter function from diplyr I only manage to create a df based on that criteria.

Can any body guide me on the right direction

**`test <- df_settlement %>%  filter(` Country Code`== 'BE' &`Order Date `>= '2022-03-18'   )`**

Comment: Have found how to make it work 
df_settlement <- df_settlement %>% 
  filter(
    `Order Date` <  B2B_StartDate | `Country Code` != 'BE'
  )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have it almost right, you just want a comma after 'BE' instead of an &. It should look like this:

```
test <- df_settlement %>%
     filter(Country Code== 'BE',
            Order Date >= '2022-03-18')
```